# Understading the Linux Kernel Scheduler

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I'm studying the Linux Kernel and am trying to figure out how the Round Robin scheduling algorithm works. In the `kernel\sched_rt.c` file, there's a method called `task_tick_rt` defined like this:

```
static void task_tick_rt(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int queued)
{
    update_curr_rt(rq);

    watchdog(rq, p);

    /*
     * RR tasks need a special form of timeslice management.
     * FIFO tasks have no timeslices.
     */
    if (p->policy != SCHED_RR)
            return;

    if (--p->rt.time_slice)
            return;

    p->rt.time_slice = DEF_TIMESLICE;

    /*
     * Requeue to the end of queue if we are not the only element
     * on the queue:
     */
    if (p->rt.run_list.prev != p->rt.run_list.next) {
            requeue_task_rt(rq, p, 0);
            set_tsk_need_resched(p);
    }
```

}

What I don't understand (besides the fact that there's a useless `queued` parameter) is what the code is trying to achieve by the `if (--p->rt.time_slice)` check. I don't understand why the task list pointer `p` is being decremented by 1, in other words, why is the method checking the **previous task** instead of the current one? Any clarification on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out c operator precedence http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

The `->` operator has a higher precedence than the prefix `++`, so this particular condition could be written:

```
if (--(p->rt.time_slice))
```

In other words, it is the timeslice which is being decremented, not the pointer.

---

The `queued` parameter may appear useless here, but it has a reason to be there.  Specifically notice where `task_tick_rt()` is called from.  Its only reference is when it is assigned to the `.task_tick` function pointer in the `rt_sched_class` instance of `struct sched_class`:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/rt.c#L1991

So we see that each scheduling algorithm has its own `struct sched_class` function vector which the kernel will call into for scheduling services.  If we look at other algorithms, we see the CFS (Completely Fair Scheduling) algorithm also has its own instance of `struct sched_class`, named `fair_sched_class`:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L6179

The `.task_tick` member in the CFS case points to `task_tick_fair()`:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5785

Note `task_tick_fair()` ***does*** make use of the `queued` parameter.  So when the `.task_tick` member is called into ([here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L393) and [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2179)), a 0 or a 1 is passed in for the `queued` parameter.  So while `task_tick_rt()` doesn't use it, the `queued` parameter must still be their so the function pointer types in the `struct sched_class` function vector all match up.

In short, the `struct sched_class` function vector specifies the interface between scheduling algorithms and the rest of the kernel.  The `queued` parameter is there should a given algorithm choose to use it, but in the case of Round Robin, it is simply ignored.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thank you for explanation of purpose of sched_class. I know that there are two scheduling policies `SCHED_FIFO` & `SCHED_RR`. However, looking at the http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v3.10/kernel/sched/rt.c#L1 sched/rt.c, I can't figure out how sched_class assist at choosing which policy to use.

Comment: @newprint - Please ask this as a new question.