# Task scheduler behaviour in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel, task, scheduling

Currently, I am doing some research on Linux task scheduler behaviour. I have some questions to be clarified-

1. In the case of Multicore architecture, a scheduler thread (kernel thread) is running per core OR  a central kernel scheduler is running on a dedicated core to handle all scheduling task.
2. How frequent a typical scheduler tick (interrupt) happens?, and what is a typical time-slice for a task (thread) of a particular priority ?
3. After a scheduler tick , is it mandatory to execute another task  from the run-queue, even though the current task does not finish its time-slice?

## Partial answer of the question 2 (**Thanks to Dervin Thunk**):

CFS (which is default scheduler for processes) has no fixed timeslice.This timeslice always in between   between sysctl_sched_min_granularity and sysctl_sched_latency (epoch length). That means the time-slice cant be less then  sysctl_sched_min_granularity. The default value of these parameters are 0.75 ms and 6 ms respectively and defined in kernel/sched/fair.c.

Along the line  The CFS scheduler calculates the timeslices for a given task just before it is scheduled for execution. Its length is variable (dynamic) and depends directly on its static priority and the current load of the running queue, i.e. the number and priority of the tasks in the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I make assumptions about your question, I think you mean the CFS (completely fair scheduler), put in place around 2007-9. It may be easier for you to find the answer to your questions by navigating the code. (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c), that's the fair scheduler, and (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/sched.h) are the definitions, some of which you ask about here. Also, you may find ([Understading the Linux Kernel Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327213/understading-the-linux-kernel-scheduler)) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Linux has a lot of schedulers:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_Fuck_Scheduler
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%281%29_scheduler

to name a few.

Comment: Is there an easy way to switch between them in Ubuntu, or do I have to patch and compile my own kernel?